# Visual studio 2012 tf command not working in logged off state

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm using visual studio 2012 and tfs to do my development When I try to get the latest files using get command in tf.exe through batch in a logged off state, below error is shown.Where else running the batch manually in logged in state gets the latest file. Could anyone please help me on this regard. Thanks in advance

TF30063: You are not authorized to access

What I have tried:

I have tried to turn on alternate authentication credential also,
tried with correct -login:credentials

Comment: Hi Jefferson, any update on this, have you figured it out? Did my reply help or gave a right direction?

Comment: No Patrick, The issue was with the account. When I try to use -login with ***@hotmail.com its not working but connecting to different tfs through Domain\Username is working.How to connect ***@hotmail.com account through -login?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You have to use an Active Directory account for on-premise TFS -- you can't directly provide a hotmail account.

---

According to the error info, you need to specific credentials  with the command in the batch script.

> **Use `/login` option to specify credentials when running a command**
>
> Use the /login option to specify the Team Foundation Server user
>   account to run a command. This option can be useful when you are
>   working at the machine of another team member.

For example:

```
c:\code\SiteApp\Main\SolutionA\Project1>tf get program.cs  /login:JuliaI,JuliaPassword
```

Comment: The issue was we are having an tfs account with ***@hotmail.com when this is provided it fails in case of Domain\username its working. Login fails for ***@hotmail.com. Could anyone help on this?

Comment: @jeffersonsam Sorry, you have to use an Active Directory account for on-premise TFS -- you can't provide a hotmail account. That's why login failed.

Comment: But I'm using the ***@hotmail account to connect to TFS. I dont have active directory account to login.When manually VS2012 is opened the microsoft login asks and I log in with the ***@hotmail account and it works for connection of tfs. Oly in command line its failing. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: @jeffersonsam Are you sure about you are using TFS? Sounds impossible, if you are using TFS you should login with account such as `Domain\yourname`  Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using the on-premise TFS url  which should be `http://xxx:8080/tfs/`or Visual Studio Team Service `https://xxx.visualstudio.com`

Comment: @jeffersonsam You are using the VSTS. With the tfs command   -login  option. You could try to use the user name/password in  Alternate authentication credentials instead of your e-mail address. In your TFS web portal top right corner, select-Security- Alternate authentication credentials. After setting this, then use this with your -login option. The url should be `https://xxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/_details/security/altcreds`

Comment: @jeffersonsam You could check the build log on VSTS. There should be something like: `tf vc workfold /unmap /workspace:ws_1_1 $/ /collection:https://xxx.visualstudio.com/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,******** /noprompt` Build server is using Oauth. Have you tried use access token do this?

Comment: @jeffersonsam Above example is not related which command  are using. It shows how VSTS build server invoke tf command with authentication `/login`. It's also not directly use hotmail email address. Afraid this is not support. You could try to use `tf get program.cs   /loginType:OAuth /login:.,$AccessToken` And you should provide full path of `tf.exe` More details please take a look at this thread: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/142592/powershell-script-tf-commands-logintype-error.html Hope it helps!